# Play RAW video data from a ByteArray

Tags: flash, netstream, actionscript-3

According to the [NetStream API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#play%28%29), Flash can play LOCAL RAW video by calling `ns.play("raw:filename");`.

My question is how can Flash play RAW video data from a `ByteArray`? I have basically set my NetStream object to data generation mode by calling `play(null)`, but whenever I call `ns.appendBytes(byteArray)` nothing is happening because apparently, `appendBytes` only support FLV data.

So now I hope that someone has also encountered this before, how can I make Flash play raw video data from a ByteArray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, you can't use appendBytes for a RAW file type.

You should be able to play your video using ns.play("raw:filename").

In terms of Flash Media Encoding, RAW is a FLV file fragment, published from the Flash Media server (usually).

If it's not acceptable to play the filename, you may need to convert the RAW file (i.e. [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/)) to encode the video into FLV format and then stream. However, I don't believe RAW files can be converted, or will require Flash Media Encoding to change: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashmediaserver/devguide/WSecdb3a64785bec8751534fae12a16ad0277-8000.html

Comment: On a slightly different note... is there a way to do the same for audio? I mean using the sound object and then calling its PLAY method while listening to its SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, i should be able to pass raw byte data to that sound object right?  I'm doing this on my SAMPLE_DATA event listener but no sound is coming out

event.data.writeBytes(soundBA, soundBA.position);

Comment: The best you can do for Sound I've found is the SoundLoaderContext (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundLoaderContext.html). Basically, set a time for pre-streaming before playing.